# Convert Union to QByteArray and vice-versa using QUdpSocket in Qt

Tags: qt, qt5, qbytearray, qdatastream, qudpsocket

I have one Union like below

```
#define no_of_bits 240
#define word_size 16

struct bits
{
    unsigned short int bit1:1;
    unsigned short int bit2:1;
    unsigned short int bit3:1;
    unsigned short int bit4:1;
    unsigned short int bit5:1;
    unsigned short int bit6:1;
    unsigned short int bit7:1;
    unsigned short int bit8:1;
    unsigned short int bit9:1;
    unsigned short int bit10:1;
    unsigned short int bit11:1;
    unsigned short int bit12:1;
    unsigned short int bit13:1;
    unsigned short int bit14:1;
    unsigned short int bit15:1;
    unsigned short int bit16:1;
};

union myData
{
        unsigned short int data[no_of_bits/word_size];
        struct bits word[no_of_bits/word_size];
};
```

I want to convert `myData` union into a `QByteArray` so that I can send it through socket using `QUdpSocket` using  `writeDatagram()` function.
So first tell me how can I convert this into `QByteArray`.

Next thing is that, On the receiver side how can I convert the `QByteArray` into the this Union `myData` again.

Comment: Difficult to tell without more code/context but... you appear to be attempting to type pun through a union.  That's undefined behaviour as far as I'm aware.

Comment: what code you need here? I just want to convert this union ```myData``` into a ```QByteArray``` so that I can send it over a network and on the receiving side how can I convert this ```QByteArray``` into the Union. Hope you understand what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `QByteArray` constructor or `QByteArray::fromRawData`.

See example for converting **to QByteArray**:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QByteArray>


#define no_of_bits 240
#define word_size 16

struct bits
{
    unsigned short int bit1:1;
    unsigned short int bit2:1;
    unsigned short int bit3:1;
    unsigned short int bit4:1;
    unsigned short int bit5:1;
    unsigned short int bit6:1;
    unsigned short int bit7:1;
    unsigned short int bit8:1;
    unsigned short int bit9:1;
    unsigned short int bit10:1;
    unsigned short int bit11:1;
    unsigned short int bit12:1;
    unsigned short int bit13:1;
    unsigned short int bit14:1;
    unsigned short int bit15:1;
    unsigned short int bit16:1;
};

union myData
{
        unsigned short int data[no_of_bits/word_size];
        struct bits word[no_of_bits/word_size];
};



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    myData data;

    // Variant 1  (no copy data)
    auto byteArray = QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&data), sizeof(data));

    // Variant 2  (copy data)
    QByteArray byteArray2(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&data), sizeof(data));

    return a.exec();
}
```

Convert **from QByteArray**:

```
assert(byteArray.size() == sizeof(data));
memcpy(&data, byteArray.data(), sizeof(data)); // Copy

// OR

assert(byteArray.size() == sizeof(data));
myData* data2 = reinterpret_cast<myData*>(byteArray.data()); // No copy
```

Actually, you can call `writeDatagram` directly:

```
QUdpSocket socket;
socket.writeDatagram(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&data), sizeof(data), QHostAddress("127.0.0.1"), 1234);
```